# SQL Query... I'm new so this is probably easy

Tags: sql-server

I can write simple SELECT statements for my SSRS reports but I have run into a wall trying to figure out how to do this query and I'm stumped. I have a table, and it has an entry in it showing me that a particular process is done. The process is Operation_Seq_NO 60 and the QTY_GOOD is 1. There IS NO ENTRY for operation_seq_no with an 80 so it goes on the report. As soon as an 80 entry hits the table, it needs to go off the report. Sounds simple but totally got me stumped. I attached a pic or it in tabular format to maybe help someone understand the issue.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Pc9.jpg]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Pc9.jpg

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`not exists()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) or `not in()` to filter rows that have a corresponding row with `operation_sec_no = 80` like so:

using [**`not exists()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx):

```
select *
from labor_ticket as t
where not exists (
  select 1
  from labor_ticket as as i
  where t.transaction_id = i.transaction_id
    and i.operation_sec_no = 80
)
```

or with `not in()`:

```
select *
from labor_ticket as t
where transaction_id not in (
  select transaction_id
  from labor_ticket as i
  where i.operation_sec_no = 80
)
```

Comment: Wow,  thanks! I wasn't expecting something so quick. Let me try this and i'll get back to you! Thanks again!

Comment: Hey @DHJ, if this solved your problem, you can select this as the accepted answer.